# Swagger 2.0 not validating for empty string

Tags: json, yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger 2.0 I have a definition like this

```
definitions:
  User:
    required:
      - name
      - skills
     
    properties:
      name:
        description: 'Donald Smith'
        type: string
      skills:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
          minLength: 1
```

name and skills are required it can accept only strings, however I am trying to validate for empty string, basically name should not be empty and skills array should contain atleast one string value. However swagger is not validating by default I tried to use the pattern '^[a-zA-Z ]+$' for name and minLength for array but it does not work out.

Answer (score 0):

To control the number of allowed values in an array, you can use those fields:

```
minItems: 1
maxItems: 10
```

Without `minItems: 1` an empty array is considered valid.

See "Array Length" section in https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array

In order to validate that name field is non empty, you need to add:

```
minLength: 1
```